# Why is are my title in my Bottom.Tab not vertically centered?

Tags: react-native

[image]

As you can see on the image the title of the navigation bar aren't centered vertically.

I tried to manipulate the headerTitlteAlign but it didn't change anything.

Also on web it's rendered properly but not on android.

Here is my code:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import HomeScreen from '@app/components/home-screen/HomeScreen.js'
import SearchScreen from '@app/components/search-screen/SearchScreen.js'


export default class App extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
                super(props);      
                var navigation = this.props.navigation;
                this.state = {
                        fontLoaded : false
                } 
        }

        async componentDidMount() { 
                try {
                        await Font.loadAsync({
                                'DMSans-Regular': require('@fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf'),
                        })
                        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true})
                } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                }
        }

        render() {
                if(this.state.fontLoaded) {
                        return (
                                <NavigationContainer>
                                        <BottomTab.Navigator>
                                                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' } }} />
                                                <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
                                        </BottomTab.Navigator>
                                </NavigationContainer>
                        );
                }
                else {
                        return (<View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>);
                }
        }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions-for-tabbartop-default-tab-bar-on-android

I did this way:

```
const tabBarOptions = {
        tabStyle: {
                justifyContent: 'center',
        },
}


<NavigationContainer>
        <BottomTab.Navigator tabBarOptions={ tabBarOptions }>
               <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' } }} />
               <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
        </BottomTab.Navigator> 
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer since you're resolved your issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing here is that the `bottomTabNavigator` expect an icon for each tab, if you don't want to usa an icon you can for them to stay in center with something like this:

```
...
<BottomTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlignVertical: 'center',
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
...
```

This will force them to appear in the center, the `BottomTab.Navigator` does have an options to hide labels but doesn't have one to hide the icon holder, that's why you need to force it with a style.

Success on your project.

Comment: Why would it wait for an icon ? And if so , why would it it be properly aligned on web and not on android knowing that I don't have an icon right now ?

Comment: Well it's funny because now I have the web view that is broken, the Home and the Search screen overlap on the web view.

Comment: I found a better solution, you can just use tabStyle in tabBarOptions and then set up justifyContent to center.

Comment: Oh, this solution works better indeed. 
As of why does the tab wait for an icon, I believe most of the bottomTab Navigations use icons and some times icons with labels, but it's kinda rare to see apps that just use labels on the bottom navigation. In any case I think they should've kept the old option `showIcon` that they had in past versions, that would solve your problem pretty fast.